# DraggableJS Import Not Working in the same Way of the Example

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, drag-and-drop, draggable

I have a Problem with Import ES6 on DraggableJS

[This Example](https://github.com/Shopify/draggable/blob/master/examples/src/content/Swappable/Flexbox/index.js)

I use this Example for my Import. And now i'm writing

```
import {Swappable, Plugins} from './node_modules/@shopify/draggable/lib/draggable.bundle';
```

But the Browser (Chrome) say me "`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {`"

I don't know why i use the same syntax and if i show on [Developer Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) it's the same syntax as i chose her.

Thanks for your Help :)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
import {Plugins} from './node_modules/@shopify/draggable/lib/plugins.js';
import {Swappable} from './node_modules/@shopify/draggable/lib/swappable.js';
```

Comment: I try, is the same Problem and i try this Solution, this have a other Error

`import Plugins from './node_modules/@shopify/draggable/lib/plugins.js';
import Swappable from './node_modules/@shopify/draggable/lib/swappable.js';`

Error:`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`